# Why is a (WPF) Window not 0.0 pixels wide?

Tags: c#, wpf, window, avalondock

Start with a blank WpfApplication and paste this in class `App`:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnStartup(e);

  var w = new Window
  {
    ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize,
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None,
    Background = Brushes.Transparent,
  };

  Console.WriteLine(w.Width);

  w.Width = 0.0;
  //w.MinWidth = 0.0; // makes no difference

  Console.WriteLine(w.Width);

  w.Show();

  Console.WriteLine(w.Width);
}
```

This just creates a new empty window (a black line).

But why does just `Show`ing the window increase its' `Width` to `2`?
The Output:

```
NaN  
0  
2
```

Probably some Windows related limitation, but where can I find this documented in e.g. msdn?

It's the source of a bug in window placement calculation in AvalonDock, and I was wondering whether I could hard-code the "`2`".

Comment: Try to use `w.MaxWidth` to limit width (not `MinWidth`).

Comment: @Sinatr adding `w.MaxWidth = 0.0;` makes no difference. Besides, the window should be able to become wider later on, but initial placement calculations rely on this _wrong or weird_ initial `Width` value.

Comment: It is quite convoluted and the subject of a very large number of bug fixes.  But it happens [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Window.cs,aff832999c41291b).

Answer (score 0):

The source of "2" is *probably* [SystemMetrics](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724385(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int smIndex);
...
var SM_CXBORDER = 5; // source http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#UIAutomationClientsideProviders/MS/Win32/NativeMethods.cs
    ...
Console.WriteLine(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER));
```

Output is "1"

So:

`1` for left border `+ 1` for right border `= 2`.